# Finding the mean of a subset of a matrix

Tags: r, subset, mean

I'm struggling with something quite simple. I am trying to find the mean of a subset of a matrix. For example, I would like to find the mean of the last 196 elements of each row in a matrix.

My code looks as follows:

```
for (i in 1:length(ratios))  
{  
    mean(ratios[length(ratios[,1])-196:length(ratios[,1]),i])  
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually just worked it out. For some reason you need to insert brackets around the row part of the ratio matrix as follows:

```
for (i in 1:length(ratios)){  
  mean(ratios[(length(ratios[,1])-196):length(ratios[,1]),i])  
}
```

Hope this helps anyone with similar problems

Comment: Try `rowMeans(ratios[(length(ratios[,1])-196):length(ratios[,1]), ]`. And the brackets are needed because `:` takes precedence. PS: If you really want the the last 196 elements of each row, you'd need `rowMeans(ratios[, (ncol(ratios)-196):ncol(ratios)]`.

Comment: @SimonO101 Thanks. The code was meant to show a better possibility. I didn't check everything.

Comment: @Roland

Thanks so much, the code worked perfectly! Much more efficient than mine

Comment: @Roland Is there perhaps a function for finding the standard deviation of the last 196 elements of each row?

Comment: @Mike what do you want to do, because the answer you accepted does not find the mean of the last 196 elements of each row. It finds the mean of the last 196 rows. That is different.

Comment: @SimonO101   
Sorry, I don't understand the difference? But I suppose, given that the answer I accepted is working, I am looking for the mean of the last 196 rows.  

I managed to solve that problem using the code you and Roland provided, but I was hoping there might be something similar for finding the standard deviation of the last 196 rows. I tried searching for something like colsd, but didn't find anything

Comment: @Mike From your question wording it implies that if you had 200 rows and each row had 200 elements you would want to find the mean of the last 196 elements on each of the 200 rows, not the 200 elements of the last 196 rows! To answer you question `apply( ratios[ ( nrow(ratios) - 195 ):nrow(ratios) , ] , 1 , sd ) `

Comment: @SimonO101  
Thanks for the reply and the help! I have no doubt that your solution is correct, but could you perhaps help me understand why I get a different answer using `sd(ratios[(length(ratios[,1])-(196-1)):length(ratios[,1]),i])`? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

This is a more direct approach

```
>rowMeans(tail(ratios, 196))
```

`tail(ratios, 196)` returns the last 196 elements of each row of `ratios`, and `rowMeans` calculates the mean for each row.

In your axample, you are taking col means, intead of row meas, so try:

```
>colMeans(tail(ratios,10))
```

Here's an example

```
> ratios <- iris[, sapply(iris, is.numeric)]
> Means <- numeric(ncol(ratios))

> for (i in 1:length(ratios))
  {
    Means[i] <- (mean(ratios[(length(ratios[,1])-10):length(ratios[,1]),i]))
 }

> COLMeans <- colMeans(tail(ratios,10))

> Means  ## Using `for` loop
[1] 6.490909 3.036364 5.336364 2.163636

> COLMeans # using `tail` and `colMeans`
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
        6.45         3.03         5.33         2.17
```

Comment: Your first version explaining tail was right (but not what was required). `tail( ratios , 196 )` will give the last 196 rows of `ratios`, not the last 196 elements of each row! Try using a transpose with colMeans... `colMeans( tail( t(m) , 196 ) )`